# Can I list multiple wage income abbreviations on Free File Fillable Form 1040?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-1040, free-file-fillable-forms

## Background

Wage income abbreviations are for taxable income not listed on a W-2. Two examples of these abbreviations are "HSH" and "SCH". Those two abbreviations are mentioned on pages 26 & 27 of the [2018 Instructions for Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf). If applicable, these abbreviations are to be listed in the space to the left of line 1 on Form 1040 (2018).

## Issue

Two wage income abbreviations apply to my income situation. However, Form 1040 (2018) in the Free File Fillable Forms software seems to support selecting only one such abbreviation from a drop-down list.

## Question

Is there a way to include more than one wage income abbreviation on Form 1040 (2018) in the Free File Fillable Forms software?